# BVI vs Bridge routers

Tags: cisco, router, ios, bridge-router

What is the difference between BVI and Bridge on Cisco IOS routers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BVI is a "bridge virtual interface" and should be the Layer 3 bit (the interface that has an IP address). The physical interface(s) attached to the bridge-group should be purely layer 2 interfaces.

Comment: OK, so that kinda tells me what BVI is,, but what is bridge group?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey If you have an interface BVI17, all interfaces with "bridge-group 17" will be in the same group and BVI17 will provide the L3 connectivity.

Comment: So.. they are not alternative options but rather they are on different levels of my configuration? Is it possible then to have a bridge group that does not have BVI? If so, then what would I lose? (access lists?)

Comment: @George Bailey: The ability for the router to interact with the interfaces on a Layer 3 level (or, as far as I recall at least). The "BVI interface" is, essentially, the same as the "Interface VLAN" on a switch (the SVI).